# Can I put a shower pan where tile USED to be?

Tags: bathroom, shower, tile

[image][image]I pulled up the tile in my bathroom. Water was underneath and had rotted the wood nearby. Now I have a concrete pan underneath where the tile used to be that slopes toward the drain. Can I put a shower pan over this concrete pan? If so, do I need to extend the shower drain?

Comment: I'm adding this as a comment because I know if it' a valid answer.  Couldn't you cover the concrete pan with a few coats of Red Guard and then tile over that?  Then use epoxy grout, which is waterproof rather than break up the concrete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At this point you really should do it right.  Since this is the basement floor, you will be placing the shower pan on the concrete.  You'll want to adjust the drain so that it can connect correctly to the shower drain.  If this concrete is already sloped (and it sounds as though it may be) you may be able to remove the sloped part if it was poured on top of the slab. Otherwise you could use some leveling compound to create a flat surface for the shower pan.

I'm assuming now that the rotted wood was in the walls.  You should use a product designed to back shower tile such as a cement backer-board rated for this use.  Your building materials supplier should be able to get you the right product.  Follow the manufacturer's recommendation for proper installation and surface preparation needed before applying the tile.

Be sure to remove and replace all the rotted wood while you have this all exposed.  It won't get better on its own.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! This is the basement so when I break up the concrete will I stop when I hit dirt?

Comment: No!  It was certainly not clear that this is the basement floor.  I've edited my answer based on this new information.

Comment: Ok thanks. I didn't realize that was pertinent information. You're exactly right, the existing concrete pan slopes gently towards the center. I don't have a good picture right now because I just ripped up the tile and am in the process of clearing it out.  I have a follow up question: If the drain is level with the existing concrete pan and I want to put a shower pan over it, will I just get a shower drain extension kit? I may end up hiring this part out, but I want to have a useful dialogue with the plumber. Thanks again.

Comment: @RachelAyoroa  Most shower pans have a drain fitting that is designed to fit into the floor drain pipe.  Usually you need to cut the pan drain to the correct length so that it fits into the floor properly.  But yes, usually the floor drain pipe is flush (or nearly flush) with the floor surface.

Comment: Hey I hope I'm not beating a dead horse here. I went ahead and cleaned up the rest of the tile today and added a picture. So if I understand your previous comments correctly, I would use some self leveller to get this area flat and then drop in a custom pan and it could fit into the existing drain? I've attached a picture. The outer area of the drain is 4" and the actual opening of the pipe is 2"